# I2C Port on Raspberry Pi RPI4 recognizing arbitrary sensors

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, i2c, multiplexer

I am using a [TCA9548A I2C Multiplexer from Texas](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9548a.pdf?ts=1638734174005&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) along with two I2C sensors 'behind' / in series with each of the 8 Multiplexer channels. The Mulitplexer has the address 0x70, the two sensors have addresses of 0x48 and 0x53 respectively.

The setup worked fine initially but at some point (and I couldn't figure out the reason) it stopped working and 'i2cdetect -y 1' now outputs sensor addresses that do not exist. I have tried different baud rates ranging from 10 to 400kHz. I think it could be a hardware issue due to bad wiring since I use tiny Dupont wires with a length of around 30cm to the multiplexer and around 140cm from the multiplexer to the two I2C sensors.

But I checked the wiring.

Why does the RPI recognize sensor addresses that do not exist? How can I further troubleshoot it?

Edit with more information: To my knowledge, the RPI4 has relatively strong 1.8k pullup resistors on the SCL/SDA lines, [as reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340441/i2c-and-pullup-resistors).

I'll troubleshoot further whether it is a problem related to the physical connection since it worked previously without any changes to the setup.

Wiring: From RPI to Multiplexer: I use 2x 15cm Dupont wires clamped over a screw terminal.

Multiplexer to PCB with two I2C-sensors: 4x 140cm AWG30 wires twisted.

EDIT:
[image]

I've analyzed the SCL signal with an Oscope and would like to understand it better now. Please see below:
[image]
The period length is roughly 10µs which should yield to around 100kHz baudrate but I have set i2c_arm_baudrate = 10000 in /boot/config.txt

For a baudrate of 400000 I get the same output on the SCL:
[image]

Comment: There is not enough information to give even a guess what is happening. Please show the schematics and wiring - we can't possibly know how you built this. For example, what resistance pull-up resistors there are on the bus, and where are they located? What wire used for the devices, and is for example the clock and data wire twisted together or how is it wired?

Comment: Tried to add more information at the end. My question mainly reduces to: can the rpi display i2c sensors that do not exist because of lose connections? I had some issues with I2C wiring previously but in those cases either no sensor or the correct sensor was shown.

Comment: So is there more pull-ups on the sensor side of I2C MUX? How are the wires twisted? How are the sensors and mux powered, do they share a ground connection with RPi?

Comment: Have you probed the end of your line with the oscilloscope? If you do not have an oscilloscope - have you tried to lower i2c speed as described in https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/02/change-raspberry-pi-i2c-bus-speed/ to ensure it's not long line trouble?

Comment: @Justme there are no additional pullups. I put 5.1k resistances there with a 'normally open' solder pad. So I could close the connection and see if it helps.

Comment: @Looongcat I have tried baud rates of 10, 100 and 400kHz and used the URL you provided previously. The system worked fine under dry conditions in the office. Now it is used at around 6°C in a very humid room. That could be an issue. I'll see if I can troubleshoot that.

Comment: @Looongcat I think the problem is 'long line' and the water adds an extra capacitance. I'll check the literature if that's the case but I can imagine. The immersion of the sensors including the cables in water was the only difference.

Comment: What is the absolute minimum pullup resistance that can be used for the RPI? I think it will be around 1-1.2k in total including the already builtin 1.8k pullup. This resistance is already quite low so I don't feel super comfortable by lowering it even more.

Comment: "The water adds an extra capacitance" - I've dealt with humidity-related troubles in crystal oscillators, but don't see how it can be the trouble for such a low speed as i2c does. Do you have an oscilloscope to "probe" this problem in real hardware?

Comment: Are you sure you can exclude water condensing from your checklist? Because if not - you'll want to add some conformal coating to your PCBA

Comment: @Looongcat The error source is definitely the immersion of the sensor probes in water. I just confirmed it today again by putting the cables with different lengths into water. I will now see how insulation or lower pullup resistance changes the behavior, thank you!

Comment: @Looongcat I use coating from MB chemicals (acrylic already), I'll look more into the cable now. The more cable is immersed in water, the worse the connection. If all 8 probes are in air, everything works flawlessly.

Comment: Not familiar with these chemicals. Maybe a simple conformal coating (by simple, I mean the one with a single layer spaying) isn't suitable for you, and you need to look into the dipping process, maybe even several times.

Comment: Also, if you'll need to push more current into your i2c bus - you might want to read about re-driving the i2c. For this purpose, you may take some i2c buffer (or bidirectional level shifter) or even make it with discrete transistors (maxim described such case in their 1-wire appnotes)

Comment: @Looongcat do you think the conformal coating will also help on the cable or just the bare components? On the bare components, I use already a coating. Anyways, I'll eventually just give the spraycoating a try.

Comment: @MarcoBobinger, I still strongly recommend sourcing out the oscilloscope. It'll be much easier to troubleshoot your system with it.

Comment: @Looongcat what's the minimum i2c baudrate for the RPI4, what minimum external pullup resistor can I add and what do you think about using an I2C repeater either just on one side or both sides?

Comment: @Looongcat jup I'll go for the oscope solution, thanks for your guidance!

Comment: I haven't used baud rates lower than 100k, but I believe <100k must be ok. Regarding the repeater, I mean that if you're lowering your pullups and GPIO can't drive it, give it an external driver that can handle this

Comment: @Looongcat can you please look at my initial questiont? I cannot see any change in the i2c frequency.

Comment: @MarcoBobinger, two things have been seen so far :) First one - your signaling is perfectly fine. Also, you can't change your baud rate for some reason, so every previous debug attempt is incorrect. Regarding the second one - it needs some investigation across the RPI community forum

Comment: @Looongcat I forgot a comma in separating in the /boot/config.txt - measured also the baud rate at 10kHz perfectly fine. In the end, it was all a grounding problem. The sensors were in a large stainless steel cage that needed some grounding with an RPI pin. The problem wasn't super obvious.